# MismatchSenderId with Web Push PHP CURL Firebase

Tags: php, firebase, curl, push-notification, web-push

I am getting the following error when trying to send a Push Notification using Google Firebase:

```
{"multicast_id":1559489545169770337,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}
```

Can anyone give any clues why please?

It is a new setup and not being imported from GMC.

manifest.json contains:

```
"gcm_sender_id": "1225****"
```

This matches "Project Settings" > "Cloud Messaging" > [Sender ID]

The code for registering the user is:

```
 function urlBase64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
    var padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
    var base64 = (base64String + padding)
        .replace(/\-/g, '+')
        .replace(/_/g, '/');

    var rawData = window.atob(base64);
    var outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
        outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
    }
        return outputArray;
    }

    function subscribePush() {
  
  
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
      if (!registration.pushManager) {
        alert('Your browser doesn\'t support push notification.');
        return false;
      }


    
      registration.pushManager.subscribe({
        userVisibleOnly: true //Set user to see every notification
        , applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array('*******') 
        //The "PUBLIC KEY PAIR" under Web configuration. Have tried with and without urlBase64ToUint8Array()
      })
      .then(function (subscription) {
      
        console.info('Push notification subscribed.');
        console.log(subscription);
        //saveSubscriptionID(subscription);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('Push notification subscription error: ', error);
      });
  
 
  
    })
}
```

My code is registering the user and the response from Firebase is (including "REGISTRATION ID"):

```
Data {"endpoint":"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/****:*****","expirationTime":null,"keys":{"p256dh":"****","auth":"****"}}
```

I am then using this PHP cURL:

```
$id = "****:*****"; // "REGISTRATION ID" from the response above. If this is wrong it throws an error ("InvalidRegistration"), so I know that this is correct.


$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

$fields = array (
        'registration_ids' => array (
                $id
        ),
        'data' => array (
                "message" => "Test"
        )
);
$fields = json_encode ( $fields );

$headers = array (
        'Authorization: key=' . "********", //This is the "Server key" above "Sender ID"
        //This matches "Project Settings" > "Cloud Messaging" > [Server Key]
        //If this is wrong it returns: INVALID_KEY error 401. So I know this is correct.
        'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

$result = curl_exec ( $ch );
echo $result;
curl_close ( $ch );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually figured this out. Instead of using the Subscription ID from the end of

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/ABCDEF:KJHASKHDASDetc
```

I used the following code, and used the TOKEN instead and used that as the "registration_ids" in the CURL post

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.6/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.6/firebase-messaging.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.6/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "****",
    authDomain: "****",
    projectId: "****",
    storageBucket: "****",
    messagingSenderId: "****",
    appId: "****",
    measurementId: "****"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
  
  
  const messaging = firebase.messaging();
  
  messaging.requestPermission()
    .then(function() {
      console.log('Notification permission granted.');
      return messaging.getToken()
    })
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log("The token is: ", result);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
    });

  
  messaging.getToken({ vapidKey: '*****-*****' }).then((currentToken) => {
  if (currentToken) {
    // Send the token to your server and update the UI if necessary
    // ...
    console.log("currentToken: ", currentToken);
  } else {
    // Show permission request UI
    console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
    // ...
  }
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Mismatch senderId error** will occure when The device token which you are using for send notificatin to specific device is wrong

Reason for wrong Device token could be developer has used wrong google service json file in Mobile app developement end.

So **Do updated google service json file with latest one** in your mobile application development and then make a build and after installing that application fetch device id and send the push notification again so it will works!!